# Maximum KL-divergence between two discrete distributions with non-zero mass on each point of support.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, machine-learning

Suppose we are given a discrete probability distribution $p$ defined over a finite set $\mathcal{S}$. We have $p(s) > 0, \forall s\in\mathcal{S}$. Suppose we now want to find the distribution $q$ that maximizes the KL-divergence $D(p||q)$  between $p$ and $q$, subject to the constraint that $q(s) > 0, \forall s\in\mathcal{S}$. What would be such a distribution?

Comment: I think in its full generality, you don't have much luck in finding such a $q$. Take a look at this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/448368 Can you make any assumptions on $p$ or $q$ to maybe make the problem easier to tackle?

Comment: Thanks! So in order to avoid the possibility of the maximum KL-divergence taking on a value of infinity, I have added the assumptions that $p$ and $q$ are non-zero at each point of their support. Under this assumption, it seems that the maximum KL-divergence between $p$ and $q$ will always take on a finite value. I am interested in knowing what that value will be. I understand that the goal here is to maximize a convex function (as opposed to minimizing it), which makes it tricky.

Comment: For strictly positive distributions, you're right it is finite. However, it can still be made arbitrarily large. Consider a Bernoulli example similar to the link with $p \sim \text{Bernoulli}(\epsilon)$, $q \sim \text{Bernoulli}(1-\epsilon)$. By picking $\epsilon$ close enough to 1 (or 0 by symmetry), you can make $D(p \vert\vert q)$ arbitrarily large, yet finite. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+-xlog%28%281-x%29%2Fx%29+-+%281-x%29log%28%28x%29%2F%281-x%29%29%2C+for+x%3E+0) ($x$ corresponds to $\epsilon$).

Comment: To further elaborate, this is happening because for those choices of $p,q$ $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} D(p \vert\vert q) = \infty$. The problem is that $p(s)$ and $q(s)$ are taking values in an open interval where the excluded limit point is catastrophic. You're right, I can't cause catastrophe, but thanks to the open interval I can get as close to it as I want. A condition like $p(s), q(s) > \delta, \forall s \in \mathcal{S}$ for a fixed $\delta > 0$ can save the day where you put a hard limit on how close I can get to the catastrophe, but then, the answer is probably going to be obvious.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks a lot. With the hard constraint of $\delta$, the answer seems obvious when $|\mathcal{S}|=2$ (as in the Bernoulli example). But other than that, perhaps the answer still needs working out.